# How to put dynamic value in Doughnutchart Using chartjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, chart.js, donut-chart

I am beginner in chartjs. I need a dynamic values updates using form table submit button.

(chartjs)

I am using Chart.min.js

```
<form>
   <ul>
     <li>
         <p>
           <label>Mobilizations</label> <input type='text' id="Doughnut-1" />
         </p>
     </li>
     <li>
          <p>
            <label>Blue print</label> <input type='text' id="Doughnut-2" />
          </p>
     </li>
     <li>
          <p>
            <label>Realization</label> <input type='text' id="Doughnut-3" />
          </p>
     </li>
     <li>
          <p>
            <label>Final Preparation</label> <input type='text' id="Doughnut-4" />
          </p>
     </li>
     <li>
          <p>
             <label>Golive & Support</label> <input type='text' id="Doughnut-5" />
          </p>
     </li>

     <li>
         <input type="button" id="submit-1" value="submit" />
     </li>
   </ul>

</form>




 var DoughnutData = [
     {
         label: "Mobilizations",
         value: 60,

         color: "#165c91"
     },
     {
         label: "Blue print",
         value: 60,
         color: "#0070c0"
     },
     {
         label: "Realization",
         value: 60,
         color: "#157cc0"
     },
     {
         label: "Final Preparation",
         value: 60,
         color: "#0d74be"
     },
      {
          label: "Golive & Support",
          value: 60,
          color: "#0a5184"
      },


 ];



 var DoughnutOptions = {
     segmentShowStroke: false,
     animateScale: true

 }
 // get Doughnut chart canvas
 var Doughnut = document.getElementById("Doughnut").getContext("2d");

 // draw Doughnut chart
 new Chart(Doughnut).Doughnut(DoughnutData, DoughnutOptions);
```

I am beginner of js & js. I need to change the static value into dynamic, using form table. If we put the value in the table & submit then will change the chart.

(chartjs)

I am using Chart.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you should read the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-prototype-methods), but I'm going to assume based on your question that you do not understand english all that well.

The method you are looking for is `.addData( segmentData, index )`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes, English is my second language. ok. 

I complete my chart. value: parseInt($("#Doughnut-1").val()),

Comment: The problem here is that the submit button sends the input value to somewhere, which reloads the page. So, in this case that won't work. What you can do is add an event listener to the input (or the button) and change values accordingly. For example, `$('button').on('click', function(){ here add processing of inputs });`

Answer (score 0):

I am already Submitted the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jsjqfinder/o2g7d9x5/4/).

```
<canvas id="Doughnut" width="310" height="350" ></canvas>
                                            <div id="Doughnut-Input">
                                                <form>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>Mobilizations</label> <input type='text' id="Doughnut-1" />
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>Blue print</label> <input type='text' id="Doughnut-2" />
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>Realization</label> <input type='text' id="Doughnut-3" />
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>Final Preparation</label> <input type='text' id="Doughnut-4" />
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li>
                                                            <p>
                                                                <label>Golive & Support</label> <input type='text' id="Doughnut-5" />
                                                            </p>
                                                        </li>


                                                        <li>
                                                            <input type="button" id="submit-1" value="submit" />

                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$("#submit-1").click(function (event) {


// Doughnut chart data
var DoughnutData = [
    {
        label: "Mobilizations",
        value: parseInt($("#Doughnut-1").val()),
        color: "#165c91" 
    },
    {
        label: "Blue print",
        value: parseInt($("#Doughnut-2").val()),
        color: "#0070c0"
    },
    {
        label: "Realization",
        value: parseInt($("#Doughnut-3").val()),
        color: "#157cc0"
    },
    {
        label: "Final Preparation",
        value: parseInt($("#Doughnut-4").val()),
        color: "#0d74be"
    },
     {
         label: "Golive & Support",
         value: parseInt($("#Doughnut-5").val()),
         color: "#0a5184"
     },
];

$("#Doughnut-Input form").bind("click", function () {
    $("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
});


// Doughnut chart options
var DoughnutOptions = {
    segmentShowStroke: false,
    animateScale: true,


}
// get Doughnut chart canvas
var Doughnut = document.getElementById("Doughnut").getContext("2d");

// draw Doughnut chart
new Chart(Doughnut).Doughnut(DoughnutData, DoughnutOptions);

});
```

});